# Run-time NZEC error in Spoj with c

Tags: c

This is my code for the problem Life,The Universe & everything. It is showing run-time NZEC error in SPOJ though it has return 0. Please help me with this.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
  int i;
  while(1)
  {
     scanf("%d",&i);
     if(i!=42)
       printf("%d/n",i);
     else
       exit(1);
   }
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is showing NZEC (Non Zero Exit Code) because you are returning 1 ( from `exit(1)` ) instead of 0.

The correct way to do it would be -:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
  int i;
  while(1)
  {
     scanf("%d",&i);
     if(i!=42)
       printf("%d/n",i);
     else
       return 0; // or you could simply write "break;" here
   }
return 0;  // This statement won't get executed anyway
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but it is showing wrong answer with this code, even with break it is showing same error on SPOJ. And even its not running on my machine. Previously code without return 0 and with exit(1) only was giving correct output on my machine but was showing error NZEC on SPOJ. I just can't understand where things are going wrong even with this simple problem. :(

Comment: Another solution which I tried using for loop is accepted by SPOJ is this:                                                                                                                                         #include <stdio.h>

      int main(void) {
      int x;
      for(; scanf("%d",&x) > 0 && x != 42; printf("%d\n", x));
      return 0;
     }

Comment: Replace `printf("%d/n",i);` with `printf("%d\n",i);`

Comment: You can accept the answer if you feel satisified !!